# R tidyverse comparing dates in piped flow doesn't work with small-medium dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, filter

I have a dataset of 700 entries with 65 columns, a few of which are dates. Here's the first 20 entries from the dataset, and the columns I need for filtering:

```
library(tidyverse)

# data frame with the sample data
df <- data.frame(
  IDs = c(600, 688, 592, 589, 685, 653, 460, 547, 520, 744, 457, 666, 502, 636, 655, 719, 565, 734, 539, 593),
  estimated_end_date = c("18 June 2021", "15 March 2022", "07 April 2021", "19 July 2021", "24 February 2022",
                         "04 October 2021", "09 December 2020", "12 April 2021", "NA", "NA",
                         "18 November 2020", "27 October 2021", "09 February 2021", "30 September 2021",
                         "07 October 2021", "26 April 2022", "24 May 2021", "08 September 2022", "11 March 2021",
                         "19 July 2021"),
  finalise_date = c("17 June 2021", "15 March 2022", "15 April 2021", "21 July 2021", "16 February 2022",
                    "04 October 2021", "03 December 2020", "27 April 2021", "03 March 2021", "03 August 2022",
                    "08 October 2020", "22 November 2021", "12 January 2021", "30 September 2021", "07 October 2021",
                    "28 April 2022", "24 May 2021", "20 September 2022", "08 March 2021", "24 July 2021")
)

# converting to characters as this is the format in which I receive the data
df$IDs <- as.character(df$IDs)
df$estimated_end_date <- as.character(df$estimated_end_date)
df$finalise_date <- as.character(df$finalise_date)

# converting date columns - the original dataset has other _date columns beyond the two used here
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches('_date')), funs(as.Date(.,'%d %B %Y')))
```

I'm trying to filter entries that have either estimated or finalise date within a specific date range

```
start_date <- as.Date('2022-06-01')
end_date <- as.Date('2022-12-31')

checklist <- df %>% 
  filter((estimated_end_date >= start_date & estimated_end_date <= end_date) | 
           (finalise_date >= start_date & finalise_date <= end_date))
```

Output:

```
  IDs estimated_end_date finalise_date
1 744               <NA>    2022-08-03
2 734         2022-09-08    2022-09-20
```

When I run the code on this sample, everything works. When I run the same code with the original dataset, the filtering is completely off and the list seems to include FALSE matches as well as TRUE ones.

For example, the entry with "18 June 2021" / "17 June 2021" is included.

```
select(head(full_ds %>% filter((estimated_end_date >= start_date & estimated_end_date <= end_date) | 
                               (finalise_date >= start_date & finalise_date <= end_date)), n=20), 
       IDs,estimated_end_date,finalise_date)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
               IDs estimated_end_date finalise_date
             <dbl> <date>             <date>       
 1             600 2021-06-18         2021-06-17   
 2             688 2022-03-15         2022-03-15   
 3             592 2021-04-07         2021-04-15   
 4             589 2021-07-19         2021-07-21   
 5             685 2022-02-24         2022-02-16   
 6             653 2021-10-04         2021-10-04   
 7             460 2020-12-09         2020-12-03   
 8             547 2021-04-12         2021-04-27   
 9             520 NA                 2021-03-03   
10             744 2022-08-03         2022-08-03   
11             457 2020-11-18         2020-10-08   
12             666 2021-10-27         2021-11-22   
13             502 2021-02-09         2021-01-12   
14             636 2021-09-30         2021-09-30   
15             655 2021-10-07         2021-10-07   
16             719 2022-04-26         2022-04-28   
17             565 2021-05-24         2021-05-24   
18             734 2022-09-08         2022-09-20   
19             539 2021-03-11         2021-03-08   
20             593 2021-07-19         2021-07-24
```

What could be going wrong?
If I create flag columns in the original dataset, e.g.

```
check <- full_ds %>%
  mutate(est_start_flag = estimated_end_date >= start_date)

head(check$est_start_flag, n =20)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

the result is completely wrong, with 1s in all entries except for the ones that have NA. If I run the isolated command in the console, the results are correct:

```
head(full_ds$estimated_end_date >= start_date, n=20)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Thank you for your help!

**Update**

This was the silliest stackoverflow question I could have asked. I had another column called "start_date" in my original dataset that was evidently conflicting with the variable "start_date" that I was using to filter the data. Thank you for the comments, they helped!

Comment: What do you get if you do `str(full_ds)`?  Also, is there any grouping applied to `full_ds`?

Comment: No grouping. This is the str output, removing the columns that are not relevant:
`> str <- str(exp)

tibble [700 x 64] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

 $ IDs : num [1:700] 600 688 592 589 685 653 460 547 520 744 ...
 $ estimated_end_date : Date[1:700], format: "2021-06-18" "2022-03-15" "2021-04-07" "2021-07-19" ...
 $ finalise_date : Date[1:700], format: "2021-06-17" "2022-03-15" "2021-04-15" "2021-07-21" ...`

Comment: What if you shared `dput(head(full_ds))`. Does the code fail with that test? We really need a reproducible example in order to be able to diagnose the problem. There must be something different about your data that we can't tell from the printed output alone.

Comment: The head data I included here is exactly the same as in my full ds - I could include more rows or other columns but I would be surprised if that has an impact. I will do a sample instead of head and see if that works.

Comment: It was another column - thank you for the help!